# When was the arbitrary constant not needed when solving ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was looking through the differential equation notes, and I found some techniques need to add an arbitrary constant $C$ after the integration, i.e. integrate by separating variables. However, I remember that, for some cases, it did not require to add the arbitrary constant $C$ after the integration.

Could you list the case where I can ignore the arbitrary $C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this happens because in the middle of the problem you just need any solution to some other problem so as to modify your existing problem. For example, in a first order linear ODE:

$$y'+p(t)y=f(t)$$

any antiderivative of $p$ is sufficient to construct the integrating factor $\mu(t)=e^{\int p(t) dt}$, so the constant of integration appearing in the construction of $\mu$ does not matter. This is intuitively obvious because such a constant enters the modified equation as a nonzero multiplicative constant, which you can always just divide out.

Similar situations happen elsewhere, such as in the method of variation of parameters. You should however have one or more constants of integration in the general solution to the problem you are actually solving...if you are asked for the general solution. Sometimes you don't really care to get the general solution and just want to solve a particular initial value problem or boundary value problem; in this case the final solution will not have any constants of integration. Finding the solution in this case may or may not involve going through the general solution, depending on the technique being used.